# Brocade FastIron Basic Switch Configuration

Tags: networking, router, routing, switching

I am new to complex switching and stumbled upon a free **Brocade Fastiron x648** Layer 3 switch. I am looking to integrate it into my home network and get it  up and running just as a switch and then expand as I learn more. For now I plan on just setting it up to do basic (layer 2) switching, but the setup page and CLI commands are daunting to take on. Is there a basic set of configurations that are required for just to get the switching up? Are there any known config files available for this kind of setup?

*TLDR: Need a basic list of configs to get a Brocade Fastiron* switch setup for basic switching

So far I have cleared the device config and reset the admin password, connected it to my ISP/demarc router on port 1, and gave a static IP to port 1, but devices connected are not able to communicate yet.

Do I need any routing protocols set?

Do I need to trunk the port connected to my ISP router?

Any other protocols that need to be set?

Thank you!

Comment: Trunk port = no | routing protocol = no | static IP = no (unless you are using it as the MGMT interface, but that's usually attached to vlan 1) for a basic working setup, you want it switching at layer-2. Layer-3 is for advanced setups, multiple subnets/vlans ect. It's so you don't need a router to connect multiple subnets/vlans.